# I need to automatically trigger ajax on color selection via jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/), because I needed a color picker which supported 'no color' or 'transparent'. If you have a better picker plugin in mind, please do let me know.

Anyway, the problem is, as soon as someone selects a color, I need to close the jPicker window and trigger an ajax call with that color value.

I tried:

```
$('#fColor').jPicker({window:{expandable:true,liveUpdate:false}});
$('#fColor').change(function(){
    $(".jPicker.Container").slideUp(200);
    buildImg();
});
```

But jPicker doesn't close on color select and update seems to be working even though I set liveUpdate to false. And the ajax function isn't triggered as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `commit` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to listen jpicker change event and get the value of it. This example is given in [jpicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) page.

```
 $('#Callbacks').jPicker(
    {},
    function(color, context)
    {
      var all = color.val('all');
      buildImg(all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'); //ajax call here
      $('#fColor').jPicker().hide(); // hide jpicker
    }
 );
```

And define your ajax call details using [jquery manual page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Here is a sample:

```
function buildImg(_color) {
    $.post("test.php", { color: _color} );
}
```